# What is a BFF Word™?

Tags: word, pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **BFF Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| BFF Words™ | Not BFF Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| gourd | bakery |
| catch | horizon |
| wizardly | doorplate |
| birdbath | bonding |
| merchants | albino |
| finish | rikshaw |
| alert | fighter |
| hybrid | beats |
| mothers | deprive |
| costume | grayhen |

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Comment: I see many rot13(navznyf)..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A BFF Word is one where:

> If you remove two letters, you are left with an anagram of an animal which is a common household pet ("man's best friend", hence 'BFF' - *Best Friends Forever*).

Namely:

> GOURD = **GO**UR**D**  DOG;
>  CATCH = **CAT**CH  CAT;
>  WIZARDLY = W**IZARDL**Y  LIZARD;
>  BIRDBATH = **BIR**D**BAT**H  RABBIT;
>  MERCHANTS = **MER**C**HA**N**TS**  HAMSTER;
>  FINISH = **FI**NI**SH**  FISH;
>  ALERT = **A**LE**RT**  RAT;
>  HYBRID = HY**BRID**  BIRD;
>  MOTHERS = M**O**T**HERS**  HORSE;
>  COSTUME = C**OS**T**UME**  MOUSE.

Furthermore, the non-BFF Words exhibit a different but related pattern - namely that:

> If you remove two letters, you are left with an anagram of an animal which is *not* a common household pet!
>
>  BAKERY = **BA**K**ER**Y  BEAR;
>  HORIZON = **HORI**ZO**N**  RHINO;
>  DOORPLATE = **DO**O**RPLA**T**E**  LEOPARD;
>  BONDING = B**ONDI**N**G**  DINGO;
>  ALBINO = A**L**B**INO**  LION;
>  RIKSHAW = **R**I**KSHA**W  SHARK;
>  FIGHTER = F**IG**H**TER**  TIGER;
>  BEATS = **B**E**AT**S  BAT;
>  DEPRIVE = DE**PRIVE**  VIPER;
>  GRAYHEN = GR**AYHEN**  HYENA.

Comment: Great job, you got it! Can you also figure out what is special about the non-BFF words?

Comment: You know what, I think I can! I'd even spotted that in ALBINO before answering - just hadn't twigged they all did it! Will amend my answer...